# How do I create a soft link programmatically in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, symlink, freebsd

How do I create a soft link programmatically in C/C++? link() system call in freebsd will create a hard link.

Comment: `symlink` function defined in `unistd.h`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The system call you want is [symlink(2)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=symlink&sektion=2).

```
#include <unistd.h>

int symlink(const char  *name1, const char *name2);
```

> A symbolic link `name2` is created to `name1`

Answer (score 7):

You can call `symlink()`

```
int symlink(const char* name1,  const char* name2);
```

A symbolic link name2 is created to name1 (name2 is the name of the file
created, name1 is the string used in creating the symbolic  link).  Either
name may be an arbitrary path name; the files need  not be on the same
file system.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. New to system programming.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17, call [`std::filesystem::create_symlink`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_symlink).